# Publishing from Webstorm to Windows Azure Website

Tags: git, azure, webstorm

I would like to deploy my web application (IDE is WebStorm) to Windows Azure Websites via Webstorm. How is this possible. I am asking because I don't want to use FTP as publishing method.

Furthermore automatic deployment from Visual Studio Online repository with Git does not work when committing and pushing code to Visual Studio.

Comment: what issue do you have with VS Online and Git? I am having number of projects on GIT source control in VS Online and have no issues with Continuous deployment to Azure Web Site. I have seen some temporary issues with clients. Issues go away once the web site is deleted and new web site is "attached" to the project.

Comment: One of the errors I got in VS is **Files in your project exceed MAX_PATH, please move your project to a location with a shorter path.** This is due to the nested structure of node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

This manual was written for PhpStorm but there is nothing that makes it PhpStorm-only (e.g. PHP code or DB support) .. which makes it applicable to WebStorm or any other IDEA based IDE as well -- it's all done via Git VCS integration:

[Working with Windows Azure from within PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Windows+Azure+from+within+PhpStorm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the manual is not about VS Online. I am using a Git repo within VS Online.